Mariadb / mysql EXPLAIN to optimize data query
I am using mariadb to store a large number of measurements. A common query I do selects for a data range. It takes a little long, something like 10 to 20 seconds, and it gets worse and worse, so I was playing around with my indices. I use EXPLAIN to see if the indices work.
But now EXPLAIN gives me a confusing output. It seems that what it does depends on the actual date range I select. For July it does something reasonable, for June not. I see it also in the query times: July is much faster. What could be the cause?
That is the output. I did not change anything else between these to queries. Only the date range. But somehow, 'type' is different, 'key' is different, 'key_len' is different, and most notably, it scans all 16 mio entries of the table.
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM eurostat_dump WHERE station_name='Izana' AND last_update BETWEEN '2024-07-01' AND '2024-07-30';
+------+-------------+---------------+-------+--------------------------+-------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table         | type  | possible_keys            | key         | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+------+-------------+---------------+-------+--------------------------+-------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | eurostat_dump | range | last_update,station_name | last_update | 3075    | NULL | 1972882 | Using where |
+------+-------------+---------------+-------+--------------------------+-------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+

MariaDB [slr_stats]> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM eurostat_dump WHERE station_name='Izana' AND last_update BETWEEN '2024-06-01' AND '2024-06-30';
+------+-------------+---------------+------+--------------------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table         | type | possible_keys            | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra       |
+------+-------------+---------------+------+--------------------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | eurostat_dump | ALL  | last_update,station_name | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 16446501 | Using where |
+------+-------------+---------------+------+--------------------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+

EDIT:
This is the table layout:
| eurostat_dump | CREATE TABLE `eurostat_dump` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `station_name` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_update` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `target_name` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `status_code` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `returns` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prediction` text DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `last_update` (`last_update`(768)),
  KEY `station_name` (`station_name`(768))
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17848007 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci |


If there are lots of rows in the June range, using the index may not provide enough improvement. The July query is better because we're only 11 days into the month, so it reduces the number of rows enough to make using the index an improvement.

A composite index on (station_name, last_update) would probably help in both queries.

What is your last_update index? Why its record length is 3 kbytes? Provide the output for SHOW CREATE TABLE eurostat_dump;

Aha, I learned a lot from these comments already. I altered two things: First, the 'last_update' field was a text. That was not good, much too big. Made it a TINYTEXT now. Probably a small VARCHAR would even be better, have to try it. Second, I made a composite index of (station_name, last_update). And everything works fine now: Both cases use the composite index, and both cases now come reasonably fast (2 seconds vs. 20 seconds). A great many thanks to both of you. (and if you write an answer, I'll accept it of course).

last_update is probably a date. (SQL - structured query language) - so emphasise structure. station_name also probably suitable for a varchar of reasonable size for the data there. Once you have the the composite index suggested earlier becomes possible. Text/blob types prohibit some forms of optimization, use them sparingly. I think all us have written these basic answers before and its getting repetitive. You can do your own answer if you want.

If you need date ranges then you need a date column, NOT text (or tinytext).   Use the correct data type for the need see: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/date-and-time-data-types/

The longest station name is Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwllllantysiliogogogoch (Wales) with a size of 58 characters. Why do you use text (=65535 characters) instead of varchar ?


If last_update is a date, use DATE or DATETIME or DATETIME(6).  Saves space and avoids prefixing issues.
Never use TINYTEXT -- it is worse than the equivalent VARCHAR(255).
When you have INDEX(a,b), don't also have INDEX(a).
Normalize station_name and target_name to an INT of the smallest practical size.

Most of the above save space, hence improving speed.

Use daily (or other unit) Summary Tables -- This leads to the queries that are much faster.
More on Sensor Tables


Okay, so thank you all for your very useful comments, and bothering with this newbie problem!
I did two things now which drastically improved the performance:

I changed the type for station_name and last_update from TEXT to TINYTEXT. (for last update maybe it would be even better to use a datetime type, but that would have some implication on the code I would need to check first)

I added a composite index on station_name and last_update. The thing I really learned here is that having two indices for the things you look for is no substitute for having a composite index on the two. (it does kind of make sense once you know it).


That brought down the average read time from 20 seconds to 2 seconds. For reference, that's how the table looks now:
eurostat_dump | CREATE TABLE `eurostat_dump` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `station_name` tinytext DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_update` tinytext DEFAULT NULL,
  `target_name` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `status_code` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `returns` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prediction` text DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `last_update` (`last_update`(255)),
  KEY `station_name` (`station_name`(255)),
  KEY `composite_1` (`station_name`(255),`last_update`(255))
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17889062 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci |


With respect, prefix keys are harmful to performance. The prefixes are the 255s in  (station_name(255), last_update(255)) (There may be some exceptions to this, but I don't think I've stumbled across any.) If you want this to be fast, use VARCHAR(255) for your text, TIMESTAMP or DATE for your dates, and don't use prefix keys. TEXT and BLOB data types are things you should avoid unless they are absolutely necessary. I get excited about this issue because WordPress's developers got this wrong and needlessly made things slower on millions of web sites.

Thank you, very interesting. I did not even put in the prefixes on purpose, in fact, I heard about them here for the first time. It would seem they come in automatically when using TINYTEXT. Could not even make them disappear. Now that I've changed to VARCHAR, they are gone.
